# Dynamically get path from js file in npm script

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, npm-scripts

```json
"scripts": {
    "build-css": "sass theme/app.scss C:\Users\ragha\AppData\Roaming\style.css"
}
```

This will only work on windows and path is hardcoded. Instead of hardcoding the path I wanna get the path to the css file from my `script.js` file where it logs the css path according to some conditions.